# How is AdS / CFT a "successful realisation" of the holographic principle?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, holographic-principle

According to the Wikipedia articles of both [AdS/CFT correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdS/CFT_correspondence) and the [Holographic principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle) state that the former was a 'successful realisation of the latter. Does that mean that the Holographic principle is a generalisation of AdS/CFT?

Comment: Add the resources recommended tag, or have a look at the r.h.s of this page, as this is probably a duplicate or related question

Comment: Hi Wave Metric & @Countto10 : Note that resource recom., which are restricted on Phys.SE. can usually not be mixed with an actual physics q., so I removed that subquestion.

Comment: It puts the mathematical meat on the bones of the ideas of holography.  People came to holography from ideas about black holes. Another collection of people were looking at cool things in gauge theories. Maldacena brought the meat. 

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-821-string-theory-and-holographic-duality-fall-2014/video-lectures/   mentions this in some detail. It's  free watch it.